# Original XML file not complete throwing exception

Tags: c#, xml, root

My original xml file is not complete it's throwing an exception: Unexpected end of file has occured . the following elements are not closed rrrr, nnnn

XML file e.g.:

```
<rrrr>
<nnnn>
<aaaa>
</aaaa>
<bbbb>
</bbbb>
```

How can I edit this file using C# to include  `</nnnn></rrrr>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest one would use `File.AppendText` method:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(filePath))
{
    w.WriteLine("</nnnn>");
    w.WriteLinw("</rrrr>");
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfect. so simple. Thanks mate.